# Sorting display objects by their display list depth

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a list containing display objects from throughout the application (insertion order).

I want to process the list either top-down (parent, child) or bottom up (child, parent). The only requirement is that either a parent is processed before any child or vice versa a child before its parent.

What is a good approach?

Edit: This question is not about sorting a list. It's about performantly retrieving the depth of a particular display object.

Edit2: Example

Display list:

```
A (root)
    B1
        C1
        C2
            D1
    B2
        C3
            D2
            D3
        C4
            D4
    B3
        C5
            D5
    B4
        C6
    B5
```

My list:

```
list = [E1, F4, A, B2, B1, C3, ..., N9, N8]
```

Bottom-up:

```
N9, N8, F4, E1, C3, B2, B1, A
```

Top-down:

```
A, B2, B1, C3, E1, F4, N9, N8
```

Note:

Does not matter if N9 before N8 or N8 before N9. Imporant is that any N is before M (first run) or any M before its children N* (second run).

Comment: So you want to drill down your display list and get a specified display object?

Comment: I already have the list containing 1..n objects. I want to process the list 2 times. First bottom-up. Then top-down. Its about setting sizes in the first run and calculating layout in the second. The list contains all objects being currently invalidated.

Comment: Another note: I am able to define what the list stores.

Comment: Pardon for asking so many questions, but where are your `N*` and `M*` nodes in the example tree? Are they omitted for a reason? Actually your nodes in the tree only go up to `D`. Are we to assume `E*` nodes are children of `D*` nodes, and so on? Man, I am stupid, aren't I.

Comment: Its just an example. B* = objects level 2, ..., N* objects (level 9) that are all children of objects M* (level 8). The example tree shows only nodes down to D* (level 4).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right:

```
    // bottom up    
    var num:int = parent.numChildren;
    var child:DisplayObject = null;
    for( var i:int = num - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        child = parent.getChildAt( i );
        // do whatever
    }

    // top down
    num = parent.numChildren;
    for( i = 0; i < num; i++ )
    {
        child = parent.getChildAt( i );
        // do whatever
    }
```

**Edit:**

Ok, based on your example, you can use recursion to do this. Something like:

```
private var m_order:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>;

private function _doSomething( dObj:DisplayObject ):void
{
    // do my thing here

    // add to our order vector
    this.m_order.push( dObj );

    var container:DisplayObjectContainer = dObj as DisplayObjectContainer;
    if( container == null || container.numChildren == 0 )
        return;

    var len:int = container.numChildren;
    for ( var i:int = 0; i < len; i++ )
        this._doSomething( container.getChildAt( i ) );
}

// then start it off with
this._doSomething( root );
```

Provided that you can do it top down first, this should be grand. To come back up (bottom-up), just reverse-traverse the `m_order Vector`.

If you need to do it bottom up first, then create the array first, then reverse-traverse, then traverse normal.

It's the easiest way I can think of. Also, not German, Irish :)

Comment: Thank you, sousage (btw. German?). Your example shows how to iterate the direct children of a parent in the default and in the reverse order. I am looking for iterating my list that way that elements living higher in the display list are always processed before objects located deeper in the display list. It's similiar to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_traversal But i do not have all the nodes of the tree and I do not want to traverse the entire tree (which would be the stage). I have a flat list in no special order.

Comment: So you have a list that is unsorted as far as parent-child relationship goes, correct? I.e. second element may be a child of eighth and so on? You want to traverse this list guaranteeing that traversal will always iterate over a parent *before* it iterates over any of its children?

Comment: Yes. Added an example to the question.

Comment: Thing is you'd have to order your list implicitly for proper traversal anyway, at least for the most straightforward implementation. Which brings me to this: where does your list come from? Why is it so random? If it's the user that imposes its order, then I understand. I will try to cook up some code for you.

Comment: Lets say there is an application that loads a fresh new styles.css and many components may change. Unfortunately the system I want to develop is generic, and I cannot make assumptions about the actual component.

Comment: using your example, the edited code will traverse your display objects top down in this order: A, B1, C1, C2, D1, B2, C3, D2, D3, C4, D4, B3, C5, D5, B4, C6, B5.

Answer (score 0):

Flex components have nestLevel, but I don't think pure Flash/As3 objects do.

Comment: Adding a `nestLevel` functionality to non-Flex code would be trivial, off the top of my head: `function nestLevel(e: DisplayObject) { var nl = 0; while((e = e.parent) != null) nl++; return nl; }` with `nestLevel(stage)` yielding `0`, for example.

Comment: My objects may be Flex objects or plain display objects.

Comment: @amn, image you have a complex UI with many levels and a list containing 1000 elements.

Comment: Oh, I don't suggest **you** use it. I merely asserted how, if someone wants to, they can leverage `nestLevel` functionality without Flex. That's why it's a comment, not an answer :)